# Tensorflow Tfrecord from csv, ""UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position already UTF-8""

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, utf-8

I have been following  this youtube to try to generate the tfrecord file from csv.

[Creating TFRecords - TensorFlow Object Detection API Tutorial p.4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kq2Gjv_pPe8&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcNK5GeCQnxYnSSaar2tpku&index=4)

1. First i convert the file from xml to csv. It showes sucessfully converted. And the file is csv and it shows UTF-8 comma format.
2. Then when i try to run the generatetfrecord.py it shows an error : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position  already UTF-8

Here is the generatetfrecord.py code:

```
"""
Usage:
  # From tensorflow/models/
  # Create train data:
  python3 generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/train_labels.csv  --output_path=data/train.record

  # Create test data:
  python3 generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/test_labels.csv  --output_path=data/test.record
"""
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import io
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict

flags = tf.compat.v1.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
flags.DEFINE_string('image_dir', '', 'Path to images')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


# TO-DO replace this with label map
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == 'tennisball':
        return 1
    else:
        None


def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf-8')
    image_format = b'jpg'
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):
    writer = tf.compat.v1.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
    path = os.path.join(FLAGS.image_dir)
    examples = pd.read_csv(FLAGS.csv_input)
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.output_path)
    print('Successfully created the TFRecords: {}'.format(output_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
```

Here is what my csv look like:
[in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bds7J.png)
[in notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T1Xg.png)

I tried many solutions from the web but no luck. Any thought?

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: In the error message, which line is throwing that error? Also, if you read it normally (like the [example in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)), does it read correctly? Trying to determine if the CSV file is actually in the format you think it is.

Comment: And is the error from this line `filename = group.filename.encode('utf-8')` ? It shouldn't be needed unless you're trying to print or log the filename somewhere. Just `filename = group.filename` should be enough.

Comment: I tried other people csv file which turns out the same error. I guess this is ecause the machine language used as my computer is used traditional chinese

Comment: If it's UTF-8 encoded then the different language isn't a problem - that's what utf-8 is for ;-) Btw which line of your code throws the error?